# Why is PostgreSQL not saving to disk when doing long-running INSERT … SELECT …?

Tags: linux, postgresql, out-of-memory, postgres-fdw

I'm using a foreign data wrapper to move a large chunk of data (with a very simple date transformation on one column) to a local database. Using a Django cursor (because I'm too lazy to pull out the credentials to create a raw psycopg2 cursor) I do this kind of query (anonymized and with a couple joins removed but otherwise identical to the original):

```
cursor.executemany(
    sql.SQL(
        """
        INSERT INTO local_table (
            foreign_key_id,
            other_foreign_key_id,
            datetime,
            comment
        )
        SELECT other_local_table.id,
               %s,
               (object_date + to_timestamp(object_time, 'HH24:MI')::time) at time zone '…',
               comment
          FROM imported_schema.remote_table
          JOIN other_local_table ON other_local_table.code = remote_table.code
        """
    ),
    [(dummy_id,)],
)
```

However, the ***local* Postgres server always gets OOM killed** after a while. I was expecting Postgres to flush the new rows to disk to avoid running out of memory, but as far as I can tell that's just not happening - `/var/lib/docker/volumes/vagrant_postgres_data` only grows by a few MB while resident memory use grows into GBs. The local server does not have enough RAM to keep the entire result set in memory, so I need a solution which doesn't involve a more expensive hardware setup.

Do I need to set something like `wal_sync_method` or `work_mem` for this to work?

---

According to the docs `executemany` should be the right tool for the job:

> The function is mostly useful for commands that update the database: any result set returned by the query is discarded.

---

Running [Postgres 10.6 containers](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres/) on Linux on both servers and Django 2.1 locally. I'm not using any extensions other than FDW.

---

Explain plan:

```
Insert on local_table  (cost=817872.44..818779.47 rows=25915 width=56)
  ->  Subquery Scan on "*SELECT*"  (cost=817872.44..818779.47 rows=25915 width=56)
        ->  HashAggregate  (cost=817872.44..818390.74 rows=25915 width=48)
              Group Key: other_local_table.id, 1, timezone('…'::text, (remote_table.object_date + (to_timestamp((remote_table.object_time)::text, 'HH24:MI'::text))::time without time zone)), remote_table.comment
              ->  Nested Loop  (cost=101.15..807974.88 rows=989756 width=48)
                    ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.57..60.30 rows=73 width=12)
                          ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.29..42.35 rows=38 width=4)
                                ->  Seq Scan on fourth_local_table  (cost=0.00..7.45 rows=1 width=4)
                                      Filter: ((code)::text = '…'::text)
                                ->  Index Scan using … on third_local_table  (cost=0.29..34.49 rows=41 width=8)
                                      Index Cond: (id = fourth_local_table.id)
                          ->  Index Scan using … on other_local_table  (cost=0.29..0.45 rows=2 width=16)
                                Index Cond: (id = third_local_table.id)
                    ->  Foreign Scan on remote_table  (cost=100.58..9421.44 rows=151030 width=20)
```

---

[postgresqltuner](https://github.com/jfcoz/postgresqltuner) suggests I

> set vm.overcommit_memory=2 in /etc/sysctl.conf … This will disable memory overcommitment and avoid postgresql killed by OOM killer.

Is that the solution?

Comment: Can you show `EXPLAIN` output for the query?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I've added it, even though I don't understand why that's relevant :)

Comment: My solution in these cases is to pick some critera to chunk  the data on so you're not dealing with quite as many rows at once.

Comment: @Donnie I'd like to avoid that because it will be a fairly significant amount of work to split things into manageable chunks *and* the overall run time will suffer.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see anything in your execution plan except the `HashAggregate` that could consume any amount of memory, and that should be limited by `work_mem`.

To diagnose this, you should first configure your system so that you get a regular OOM error instead of invoking the OOM killer. That means to set `vm.overcommit_memory = 2` with `sysctl` and adjusting `vm_overcommit_ratio` to `100 * (RAM - swap) / RAM`.

When the server gets an OOM error, it will dump the current *memory contexts* and their size to the PostgreSQL log. This should give an indication where the memory goes. Add it to the question in case of doubt.

Are you using any third-party extensions?

Comment: Do you recommend adding swap as well? Because I don't have any yet.

Comment: Every system should have some swap, but that's unrelated.